# Windows 7 Pro 64 bit not recognizing 8 Gb of RAM

Tags: windows-7, memory, 64-bit

I have a Toshiba Satellite M645 running Windows 7 64bit Pro.  The specification states that this particular machine can use up to 8Gb of RAM.

The specs state the RAM is:

```
DDR3 1066MHz (PC3 8500)
```

- I purchased two 4Gb modules and...
- Shut down the notebook
- Removed power cord
- Removed battery
- waited 10 seconds...
- removed and replaced (carefully and grounded) the SODIMMS respectively 2Gb with 4Gb.
- Replaced battery
- Plugged notebook back in
- Windows 7 Freezes on logo screen:

  Starting Windows...

But the logo never appears and it just hangs for a long time... better than 15 minutes and I finally got tired of waiting.  This is the ONLY behavior I have been able to get when the 4 Gb memory modules are present.

The BIOS recognizes all 8 Gb (8192 Mb) and the same SODIMMS work in a 64 Linux system without any issues.  When I replace the new 4Gb modules with the original 2Gb modules, Windows 7 starts fine.

Please advise.

Comment: Are you able to enter Safe Mode by pressing F8 just before logo screen.  Likley have to press F8 frequently after POST

Comment: With the modules installed, try resetting the BIOS to defaults.

Comment: I will try both of your suggestions.  It will take some time to cycle the process.

Comment: Okay I reset to bios defaults. No luck.  I Also tried to enter safe mode and the boot hung on: Loaded: \WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DRIVERS\CLASSPNP.SYS

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you fall within the [Maximum memory amount for your laptop](http://www.crucial.com/upgrade/Toshiba-memory/Satellite+M+Series/Satellite+M645-S4049-upgrades.html), so that's not the issue.

The most likely problem is bad RAM. Try the modules one at a time and see if they work on their own. If only one works, the other one is bad, in that case you may be able to swap it out on warranty.

Comment: But they both work in another system.  How could one be bad under those circumstances?

Comment: Did you have both SODIMM's filled with the 2GB or only one? if only one, a bad connector?

Comment: I put the SODIMMS (both 4gb) into the Linux system.  All 8Gb was recognized and the system ran just fine.  If either module were bad, I would think even if the Linux system ran, that only 4Gb would have been recognized.

Comment: @AndroidAddict Good point.

Comment: @AndroidAddict Maybe try one card in each slot in the laptop? Just to confirm that the slots are not broken?

Comment: Given both 2Gb modules are recognized, it's not likely the hardware.  Something else is going on.

Comment: Tried 1 4Gb card with 1 2Gb card - no luck.  Exchanged 4Gb card and tried again - no luck.  Curiously, sometimes the system reboots once and then hangs!